# Trying to fill a website (webform) Textbox from a Dataset

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I'm having trouble getting the DataSet into a webform textbox with the name PrefixDescription. I tried to convert the row into a string, and I then tried to put the string into the textbox. However, nothing appears in the textbox. The DataSet does have data. I tried databinding and databind, but those don't work either.

```
 private DirectoryEntry testAD = new DirectoryEntry();
 private DataTable DT = new DataTable();

 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(testAD);
        SearchResultCollection myResults = search.FindAll();
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
        DT.Columns.Add("name");
        DT.Columns.Add();

        foreach (SearchResult SR in myResults)
        {
            DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();
            DirectoryEntry DE = SR.GetDirectoryEntry();
            dr["name"] = DE.Properties["name"].Value;
            DT.Rows.Add(dr);
            DT.AcceptChanges();
            PrefixDescription.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["name"]);
            DE.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `DE.Properties["name"].Value` evaluates to a non-empty string?

Comment: I doubled check to make sure DE.Properties["name"].Value had a value and it does

Comment: can you store that value to a string, then set the textbox.Text to that value - just to avoid whatever may be happening while setting and getting that same value from the DataRow object. Also, set the textbox.Text to some hard-coded value to make sure you don't have unrelated issues with that particular control.

Comment: When I first look at this, the 1 glaring thing is PrefixDescription.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["name"]); will always overwrite the PrefixDescription.Text.  So the last row always wins.  I dont know if that is part of your problem but it seems like it defintely could

Comment: string texttest = "";    texttest = Convert.ToString(dr["name"]);       PrefixDescription.Text = texttest;

Hmm I added this to save the value within a string. It is pulling from a production AD so that would be a thousand or so users...

Comment: True Etch, is there a way to have the field populate without the loop overriding each result?

Comment: bullseye - Etch! Well, nhat, which property's name do you want in the textbox? first, last, all? For all, change `PrefixDescription.Text =` to something like `PrefixDescription.Text += "," + `, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better yet, use a `StringBuilder`, something like this..

```
    System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    foreach (SearchResult SR in myResults)
    {
        DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();
        DirectoryEntry DE = SR.GetDirectoryEntry();
        dr["name"] = DE.Properties["name"].Value;
        DT.Rows.Add(dr);
        DT.AcceptChanges();
        builder.Append(Convert.ToString(dr["name"]));
        PrefixDescription.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["name"]);
        DE.Close();
    }

    PrefixDescription.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Ok awesome that works, just the application seem to error out sometimes since it takes so long to pull everything from AD. Thanks I can continue working on improving on it.